# Custom Validator to MultipartFile

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-validator

I'm trying to build a custom validator to check a `MultipartFile` using `Spring` `Validator`,  but I'm facing this issue :

```
 An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult br.com.mobtrack.api.resource.CityResource.uploadImage(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
```

This is my Validator class:

```
@Component
public class MultipartFileValidator implements Validator{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return MultipartFile.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        MultipartFile file = (MultipartFile) o;
       if (file == null || file.isEmpty()){
           errors.reject("image","send a valid image. );
       }
    }
}
```

This is my `RestController` :

```
 @PostMapping("/image")
    public DeferredResult<String> uploadImage(@Valid MultipartFile image, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            throw new ImageNotFoundException("test");
        } else {
            DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ImageStorageRunnable(image, deferredResult, imageStorage));
            thread.start();
            return deferredResult;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> "BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply"

It has nothing to do with the validator.  It appears to be with the controller.

It seems to be telling you the issue.  You need to using the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart annotations to tell it where to look for the data to bind.

Comment: Tried them how.   They are not in the example provided.   Are they immediately after the model as described in the message?   What happened when you did that?  Same error did the error change?   Just saying "does not work" or "got an error" does not give anyone anything to work with.